# Using For+noun, in conversations

Tags: american-english, prepositions

I'm currently studying English in the US and I heard a lot of people start sentences with 'for~'. 
For me, it sounds like it means 'as for' or 'when it comes to'. Is that right?
 If so, is it common and grammatically correct?
Ex)
'For Question number 2, I think~'
'For the essay we wrote yesterday, is it going to be graded?'

Answer (score 1):

It is common, but you should be aware that English people use for dialogue  is different than Proper English. While it may be relatively ok to use slang when talking it's not a good idea in reports, technical writing or anything like that where clarity of what's being said is important. 'For' in those situations is being used exactly what you're saying. It requires context to make sense which is why it's really only useful in dialogue.

Even though it means the same thing one proper way to ask your last example would be "I'm wondering if the essay we wrote yesterday is going to be graded?". 'For' isn't used here because context is provided in the sentence. Since it requires more effort to say this most people don't talk like this anymore except in certain settings.